# When using Alamofire, what does value of tuple type has no member validate mean?

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm working towards a solution to authenticate with Microsoft Azure using JWT bearer tokens which doesn't use a simple username and password but rather a client id, client secret, and two other parameters.  The authentication process works when ran in Postman however when I recreate the solution in Xcode using Alamofire, it displays a 400 error.  I'd like to print out to the console, the Alamofire request so that we can see how Alamofire is structuring the URL.

When I attempt to put Alamofire's request class method inside a print function, it won't compile and I receive the Xcode error:

```
Value of tuple type '()' has no member 'validate'
```

Here is the line of code where I'm attempting to print to the console:

```
print(Alamofire.request(authorizationURL, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .queryString), headers: headers))
```

Comment: So far, the code you providing should work fine, could you provide the code that causes the error?

Comment: @AhmadF thank you for your comment because it made me persist, I realized I placed the print statement within the Alamofire request block before my .validate statement.  By moving the print statement to outside of the request statement it works.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I placed the print statement within the Alamofire request block before my .validate statement. By moving the print statement to outside of the request statement it works.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON


class Stackoverflow: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        Stackoverflow.getAzureTokenOld()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @objc class func getAzureTokenOld(){

        let authorizationPath: String = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID/oauth2/token"
        if let authorizationURL: URL = URL.init(string: authorizationPath){
            //do stuff with your authorization url
            let parameters: [String: Any] = [
                "grant_type" : "client_credentials",
                "client_id" : "testID",
                "client_secret" : "testSecret",
                "resource" : "https://rest.media.azure.net"
            ]

            let headers = [
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Keep-Alive": "true"
            ]
            Alamofire.request(authorizationURL, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .queryString), headers: headers)



                .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
                .responseJSON { response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success:
                        print("Validation Successful")
                        let value = response.result.value
                        print("The valued response is: \(String(describing: value))")
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                    debugPrint("checking checking: \(response)")
            }
            print(Alamofire.request(authorizationURL, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .queryString), headers: headers))
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Also if you're working with Microsoft Azure Media Services using Alamofire, you may want to change your encoding parameter to URLEncoding.default to get a successful response.